# Lang parameter redirects to subfolder, keep the lang folder name on the next link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

The requirement was to have:

```
http://xxxx.com/it/
```

To redirect to

```
http://xxxx.com/index.php?act=setlang&val=it
```

An the same t to happen for the rest of the links e.g

```
http://xxxx.com/it/test.php
```

to

```
http://xxxx.com/test.php?act=setlang&val=it
```

I have achieved that using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ index.php?act=setlang&val=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ $2.php?act=setlang&val=$1 [L]
```

The problem is that I would have like to have continuity of the language in the url path and retain it when changing links unless the lang var changes

When I visit `http://xxxx.com/it` (the language will be set to Italian as expected), when I click on the next link e.g test.php the link will be `http://xxxx.com/test.php` not `http://xxxx.com/it/test.php`.

Is there a way to retain it using htaccess until manually changed by the user (user selects another language)

The reason that I am looking to retain it is for SEO purposes really, not sure if it makes any difference? but i presume that if Google had to index 3 test.php (coming from it,en.fr) it wouldn't be able to crawl the individual languages at all?as well as if it has to crawl en/test.php fr/test.php and it/test.php..

Note: As you have guessed the sub-folders don't actually exist and in reality are virtual folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the language code sticky you can create a cookie first time then `/it/` URL is loaded and then prefix every URI that doesn't have it.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if lang cookie is set and URI doesn't start with 2 char lang code
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} LANG=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?![a-z]{2}/).+)$ /%1/$1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ /index.php?act=setlang&val=$1 [L,CO=LANG:$1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ $2.php?act=setlang&val=$1 [L,CO=lang:$1:%{HTTP_HOST}]
```

Comment: thanks but adding the following line RewriteRule !^([a-z]{2})/ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC] gives me an http500 error visting every link, htaccess here: apaste.info/7YrQ –

Comment: Is it possible for you to check Apache error.log for the actual reason of this 500 error?

Comment: Sure: [client xxxx] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks , I have enabled mod_rewrite log and I can see the following: http://pastebin.com/kuTGQ2sf

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47264/discussion-between-athanatos-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to retain it using htaccess until manually changed by the user (user selects another language)

Htaccess can only change the content of your pages through something like an HTML Proxy, where all the content of your site is filtered through rules and links will magically get changed to include things like `/it/` in front of them before they're returned to browsers.

What you should probably do is in your php files, dynamically add a URI base using the contents of the `val` parameter. So if the request is:

```
index.php?act=setlang&val=it
```

index.php will include a

```
<base href="/it/" />
```

in the page's headers. That way, your links will appear to be:

```
http://xxxx.com/it/something.php
```